# Java file download isn't downloading an exact copy of the file

Tags: java, servlets, download

I have a Java servlet that implements a file download.  It includes the following code:

```
String filename = request.getParameter("filename");
File file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
String mimeType = servletContext.getMimeType(filename);
if (mimeType == null)
    mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
logger.trace("MIME type for " + filename + " is " + mimeType);
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
outputStream.close();
if (inputStream != null)
    inputStream.close();
```

On the server we have a file.tar.gz, and when the browser sends the request to download that file, I see a line in the log file saying that the "MIME type for file.tar.gz is application/x-gzip".  But when we compare the file that the browser saved to the file on the server, they are not the same.

Then I commented out the "if (mimeType == null)" line so that the MIME type would always be set to "application/octet-stream", and the downloaded file still wasn't identical to the one on the server.

Any idea why the downloaded file isn't exactly the same as the file on the server?

EDIT: This is really strange.  I tested a text file, a PDF file, a ZIP file (created in Windows), a JPG file, and they all download exact copies.  Just this file.tar.gz doesn't get downloaded exactly for some reason (on the server it's 882,273 bytes, and the downloaded copy is 881,968 bytes).

EDIT 2: When I use curl to download the file.tar.gz, it gets saved as an exact copy, so that tells me there's nothing wrong with the servlet code.  Chrome is modifying the file before it saves it for some reason.  Could Chrome be detecting that the file is a gzipped file and thinks that the server compressed the response (when it really didn't), so it tries to uncompress it?  Then again the file that Chrome saves is smaller than the file on the server...

Comment: What you mean by not exactly same? Please explain at bit more.

Comment: I mean when I diff the downloaded copy and the original, they are different.

Comment: And what is different? Try it with a text file.

Comment: File sizes are different, and also since a tar.gz file is binary, it shows a lot of bytes as being different.  We also tried a tar -zxvf on the original file and it worked, but when we tried tar -zxvf on the downloaded file, there was an error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis But we need this to work with a .tar.gz file, so even if the download works with a txt file, that won't help us.

Comment: Try it with a text file to see what is missing from the file. Maybe you aren't reading/writing all the bytes. Binary or text, it's all just bits to a computer and bytes to Java.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis A text file worked just fine.

Comment: Was it larger than 1024 bytes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes it was 18,204 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurred due to a bug in Chrome, as described here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=268085

Our web server was configured to use HTTP gzip compression for everything sent back to the browser, so due to the Chrome bug, it ended up saving the file with another layer of gzip compression.